# CSS Triangles not aligning correctly on fluid width active tabs

Tags: css

[On my page here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/restaurants/chinese-restaurants/mizu-brentwood-402.html) I've added CSS triangles to the fluid width active tabs, but they're not aligned correctly in each one.

E.g. the About Us one is OK and centrally aligned, but the others are too far right. It's the `left: 23%;` which is causing it, but I'm not sure how to get each one centrally aligned as the tabs are fluid width.

Here's the CSS Triangles for the active tabs:

```
#middle .Advert .tabs li.active .up, #middle .Advert .tabs li.active:hover .up {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
top: 16px;
left: 23%;
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
border-left: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border-right: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border-bottom: 5px solid #FFF;
margin-left:-10px;
}
```

And the Advert tabs list:

```
#middle .Advert .tabs li {
background: #EEE;
padding: 8px 0;
float: left;
cursor: pointer;
width: 19.77%;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid #C8CBCE;
border-left: 0;
}
```

Let me know if you need more CSS and any help would be great.

Comment: What is this "magic number" left: 23%; ?

Comment: Ha indeed, it was just to centrally align the first one to test, but it's not right obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the solutions could be to absolutely position the ups, like so:

Add "position:relative;" to the list item (.featurestab)

have the .up style like so:

```
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
bottom: -1px;
left: 50%; //start of image is always at halfway - this is not enough
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
border-left: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border-right: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border-bottom: 5px solid #FFF;
margin-left: -5px; //move it half the width of the .up itself to the left making it perfectly centered
```

The point of this is to always put the .up at half the width, but then always move it half of the width of the .up itself, making it always exactly at the middle.

Comment: I agree with this answer, I had to do this on my blog: https://tothought.cloudfoundry.com/resume/skills/4/detail/github/detailpage/0  You can inspect the css/html to see another example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a real boiled down example using fixed position:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1<div class="arrow"></div></li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.arrow{
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid white;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 21px;
}

li{
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  height: 23px;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**Javascript/Jquery**

```
$("li").click(function(){
  $(".arrow").remove();  
    $(this).append($("<div/>",{"class":"arrow"}));
});
```

**Working Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/jWz75/